# PowerShell implicit value property in where-object

Tags: powershell, where-clause

Is it possible to convert following **where** PS script block

```
$env:Path -split ";" | where {$_ -like "c:\Program*"}
```

to a **where** comparison statement looking like

```
$env:Path -split ";" | where ???WHAT HERE??? -like "c:\Program*"
```

What I need is something that would replace the implicit **$_** variable from the first statment.

Edit: My intention is pure curiosity. I prefer to use the second way of the where-object cmdlet, however, I do not know how to address the pipe value directly on the left side of the **-like** operator

Edit2: **What is a comparison statement?** A comparison statement is much more like natural language. Comparison statements were introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0. An example:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object PriorityClass -eq "Normal"
```

Source: [Where-Object on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6#description)

Comment: It's completely unclear what your intentions and reasons are. Why you would replace `$_` with something? What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: As `$env:Path -split ";"` returns a string array there are no properties you could address directly in the comparison statement. There is AFAIK no way to avoid the script block.

Comment: If ( ($env:Path -split ";").Contains('C:\Program') ) {…}

Comment: @f6a4 How is that using `Where-Object` comparison statement syntax?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to convert following where PS script block
>
> ```
> $env:Path -split ";" | where {$_ -like "c:\Program*"}
> ```
>
> to a where comparison statement looking like
>
> ```
> $env:Path -split ";" | where ???WHAT HERE??? -like "c:\Program*"
> ```

No, that is not possible.

There are two modes for `Where-Object`.  Fully expressed, one looks like this:

```
ls | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Name -eq 'File.txt' }
```

Here, we're writing a scriptblock that contains an expression that is evaluated on every item.

The other mode, fully expressed, actually looks like this.

```
ls | Where-Object -Property Name -Value File.txt -Eq
```

Note that the `-Eq` here is a *parameter* and *not* an operator. We're calling a command, not writing an expression in a scriptblock here. And I know what you're thinking.  "But to work that way, the command would need to have a different parameter set for every conceivable operator!"  And [that's exactly what they do](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Where-Object?view=powershell-6)!

```
Where-Object [-InputObject <PSObject>] [-Property] <String> [[-Value] <Object>] [-EQ] [<CommonParameters>]
Where-Object [-InputObject <PSObject>] [-Property] <String> [[-Value] <Object>] [-NE] [<CommonParameters>]
Where-Object [-InputObject <PSObject>] [-Property] <String> [[-Value] <Object>] [-LT] [<CommonParameters>]
[...]
```

The `-InputObject` parameter is the value from the pipeline. `-Property` is the first positional parameter. `-Value` is the second positional parameter.

The problem is that the `-Property` parameter is *mandatory*.  You can't call this command without specifying a parameter name and there's no property name that means "this object".

Comment: Thank for a nice elaboration. I believe they could either 1) add yet another parameter set where there would be something like the -bareInputObject switch instead of the -property parameter designating that the bare input object should be used or 2) add some special reserved property like '$' that would represent the input object.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own pipe function like this:

```
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Collections

    function where-special { 
    [cmdletbinding()]

    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [object[]]$piped,
        [Parameter(Position=1, ParameterSetName="eq")]
        [object]$eq,
        [Parameter(Position=1, ParameterSetName="like")]
        [object]$like,
        [Parameter(Position=1, ParameterSetName="match")]
        [object]$match )

    Begin {
        [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]$found = @()

        $toDo = [Scriptblock]::Create( 'if( $piped -' + $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName + ' $' + $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName + ') { $found.Add( $piped ) }' )
    }

    Process  {

        & $toDo
    }

    End {
        return $found.ToArray()
    }
}


$env:Path -split ";" | where-special -like 'C:\Windows'
```

Comment: That is a nice idea. It, unfortunately, does not answer my original question. Since i would like to use also other operators like -eq, -match....

Comment: Arrays have no properties to use the where-object. But you can convert the array to a custom object and use the where object afterwards: $env:Path -split ";" | % { new-object psobject -property @{ filepath=$_ } } | Where-Object -Property filepath -Like 'C:\Win*'

Comment: I've added more functionality to the solution, so you now can use like, match and eq. It's easy to add all functionality you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
$env:Path -split ";" | where { $_.StartsWith("C:\Program") -eq $True }
```

Comment: The question is more about not using the script block.